# ProgramData/Package Cache Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2015, application-settings

I am looking for clarification as to what the purpose of the C:\ProgramData\Package Cache directory is used for?  I know it holds packages for Visual Studio, similar to something like a package.json for a Node.js project.

I don't understand the need for the encrypted folder naming to hide the package?  And how you can tell the difference between valid and invalid package directories?

I could always just remove the ones in question to a side folder and see what breaks, but Visual Studio is a pain, rather avoid the headache.

Comment: I am mostly inquiring because I had an issue with NuGet package Manager not installing correctly.  I saw recommendations of clearing out this directory and then go into the extensions and reinstall NuGet package Manager.  However I removed all NuGet related files and then started getting all kinds of errors.

Comment: this is the newer location of C:\windows\installer where MSI files created with latest WIX version are cached

Comment: @magicandre1981 thanks.  Is this for all apps though or just Visual Studio.  I have run into all kinds of issues with installed extensions within VS.  My problems began when I removed all the MSI's for the NuGet extension and everything just broke.  Stupid to not just copy them and test.  But, still I thought at the very least if I removed all and uninstalled/installed that I would've resolved that issue.  However, it only got worse.

Comment: this is for all new applications that use WIX (http://wixtoolset.org/) to generate installers